# How to use RSA token or MFA for Azure VPN connection

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I have a Vnet on azure serving some production servers. I want to use some MFA like RSA Token while Client user are connecting to Azure VM's

Could you please suggest some references.

Answer (score 0):

Azure VPN Gateway currently does not support MFA, it's only cert-based authentication for the VPN client-server functionality. (It's called Azure P2S VPN.)

Your best bet is to deploy a VPN server appliance (virtual form factor) that supports the MFA of your choice in your Azure VNet to serve as the VPN server.

Thanks,

Yushun [MSFT]